# Prove that $M$ is mid-point of $XY$.

Tags: geometry

Let triangle $ABC$ inscribed  $(O)$. $AO$ cuts $(O)$ at $D$. $E$ is a point in opposite ray of $DA$. From $E$ draw a perpendicular line to $AD$ cuts $BC$ at $T$.Tangent by $T$ touches $(O)$ at $P$($P$ is on the different side from $A$ by $BC$). $AP$ cuts $TE$ at $Q$. $M$ is mid-point of $AQ$. $TM$ cuts $AB,AC$ at $X,Y$, respectively. Prove that $M$ is mid-point of $XY$.

My teacher said that Harmonic division will help[image]

I let $TX$ cut $(O)$ at $F$ and $G$, then I tried to use Butterfly theorem which let me to prove $M$ is mid-point of $FG$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $BM$ intersect the circle again at $Z$. Pascal's theorem applied for hexagon $BZPPAC$ gives that the points $BZ \cap PA = M$, $ZP \cap AC$, and $PP \cap CB = T$ are collinear. In other words, lines $TM$, $ZP$, $AC$ are concurrent. This shows that $Y$ lies on $PZ$.

Note that the angles $DPA$, $TPO$ are right. It follows that quadrilaterals $QPDE$ and $TEPO$ are cyclic. We have
$$\angle QPE = \angle QDE = \angle MOE$$
where the last equality follows from $OM \parallel DQ$. This shows that $OMPE$ is cyclic. Therefore points $T$, $E$, $P$, $M$, $O$ are concyclic. In particular $\angle TMO = \angle TEO = 90^\circ$.

[image]

Since $TMO=90^\circ$, $M$ is the midpoint of $FG$. Butterfly theorem implies that $M$ is the midpoint of $XY$.